# How to Sum Total in Header Detail Tables

Tags: sql

Please, I need your help, I'm new to the subject, so I have tow tables Order table and Order Detail table. I want to sum order amount in the order table and group by the product id exists in the order detail table. I'm getting repeated rows.

```
select p.productName 
       SUM(o.Amount - o.discount) as OrdersTotal
  FROM dbo.order o
       inner join
       OrderDetail d
    ON o.orderid = d.orderid
       inner join
       dbo.product p
    ON d.productid = p.productid
    where o.orderdate >= @fromdate
      and o.orderdate <= @todate
group by p.productname, o.discount
```

the result I'm getting is as follow

```
product name    orders total
------------    ------------
product A       150
product A       20
product B       45
product B       13
```

so please, how can I fix this result? Thanks

Comment: Remove `o.amount` from the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only group on the product name, so that all records with the same product name are included in the sum of the amount:

```
select p.productName 
       SUM(o.Amount) as OrdersTotal
  FROM dbo.order o
       inner join
       OrderDetail d
    ON o.orderid = d.orderid
       inner join
       dbo.product p
    ON d.productid = p.productid
    where o.orderdate >= @fromdate
      and o.orderdate <= @todate
group by p.productname
```

Comment: OK, but I forget to add the discount column to subtract it from the amount, so when I execute the statement I'm getting an error (discount is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Comment: Edit your question to put **ALL** the data

Comment: I did, and I'm sorry for the mistake